# How to escape special regex symbols from string

Tags: regex, extjs

I am using following regex to match a value in csv string.

```
for example: csvString = "abc-d, xy%z, efgh, ijklm, nopq(1)rst, uvw@xy"
valueString = "xy%z";
var regExp = new RegExp('(^|, )' + valueString + '(,|$)');
csvString.replace(regExp, "")
```

Above regExp is works well for any value in csvString except for value 'nopq(1)rst'. It fails when the valueString contains '()' brackets, for example valueString = "nopq(1)rst";. I want the regular expression to match whatever the valueString contains.

How to escape special regex symbols like '(' ')' '[' ']' '\' etc from string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`escapeRegex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.String-method-escapeRegex) method. It escapes any special characters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote your input string to escape all the regex special characters:

```
var regexpSpecialChars = /([\[\]\^\$\|\(\)\\\+\*\?\{\}\=\!])/g;
var regExp = new RegExp('(^|, )' + valueString.replace(regexpSpecialChars,'\\$1') + '(,|$)');
```

Reason why `nopq(1)rst` is failing to match because `( and )` are special regex symbols that are used for grouping, effectively making your regex as:

```
 (^|, )nopq1rst(,|$)
```

Comment: I am using this in ExtJs. There is no Pattern class

Comment: Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: Why is '\\$1' used for?

Comment: That is for escaping all the special characters found in your input. So `nopq(1)rst` becomes `nopq\\(1\\)rst`